# use PS script to replace text for each line from input file

Tags: powershell, loops, ps

I want to replace text in a file.txt with another text and add a new line with a new entry each time.
for example file.txt contains:

```
my wall is blue
```

I want to  have an output.txt file that will take all colours from an input file colours.txt and repeat the above sentence using these colours
colours.txt file contains:

```
white
red
green
black
```

output.txt should be:

```
my wall is white
my wall is red
my wall is green
my wall is black
```

I used the below to replace 1 occurance but how to read from the colours.txt file to create the output.txt file

```
(Get-Content -path C:\file.txt) -replace 'blue','white'| Out-File -encoding ASCII C:\"output.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the text

```
$line = Get-Content -path C:\file.txt
```

Apply each color to it.

```
Get-Content colours.txt | Foreach-Object {
    $line -Replace 'blue',$_
} | Set-Content C:\"output.txt -Encoding UTF8
```

This is based on your example so it's assumed it's one line with only the color blue to be replaced.

Comment: In fact I want it to write the same string everytime using an entry from colour.txt.so the output is 4 lines in my example. If not possible, 
I can have 4 entries of the same line if that would help. And then each line is replaced by an entry.
Thanks

Comment: What I presented creates your exact desired output.txt

Comment: Hello Doug, I appreciate your help.

Comment: Hello Doug, I appreciate your help. There was 1 curly bracket before | Set-Content that I didn't know where it was opened. however I found it. can't thank u enough: $line = Get-Content -path C:\File.txt
Get-Content colours.txt | Foreach-Object {
    $line -Replace 'blue',$_
    } |Set-Content C:\output.txt -Encoding UTF8

Comment: Thanks alot, what if I want to increment the name so that the output would be: my wall is blue1
my wall is blue2
my wall is blue3
my wall is blue4

And in this case I would definitely want it to loop for 100 times for example